# the pdf divided by the bin edge size in numpy.histogram density param

Tags: numpy, histogram, probability-density

Why is the first value returned by numpy.histogram which expressed like : n/db/n.sum() uses bin width "db".

I couldn't picture the wisdom behind dividing the number of elements in a bin by the bin width "db" then dividing it by the sum of element. the docs say it a normalized value that way. I can imagine normalizing only when dividing by a larger number to get the percentage, but how does that work in this case. 
why its not just n/n.sum() and neglect the bin width entirely, since it gives normalized values its integral equals to 1 ? why we are exactly dividing by bin width ? and what difference it makes in a same size bin width histogram ?

if density == true:

```
db = np.array(np.diff(bin_edges), float)

return n/db/n.sum(), bin_edges
```

Comment: The integral over a "histogram-like" function, i.e. a function composed of rectangles is the sum of the rectangle areas which equal width x height. In your case you thus get (db *  n / db / n.sum()).sum() which sums to one as it should.

Comment: but then n/db/n.sum() would mean height/n.sum() , since n/db is the height of the rectangle . so what height/n.sum() mean and how is it normalized in anyway ? what Im saying is , what can I do with n/db/n.sum() alone , how does it benefit me and in what sense we can call this a normalized value.

Comment: n/db is the height given the sample size. If you want the density which is independent of sample size you have to normalize by the sample size which is n.sum().

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't in this case differentiate between height and number of elements in a bin all I understand is that the height is something we don't observe in a histogram ? because all I see in the Y axis is "n" in this case. and if I try to calculate the height for a bin_width that is less than 1 , the result comes ridiculously high. why don't I just make density = 0 and just normalize the result (n/n.sum()) to get the same pdf and no headache ? I spent 48 hours trying to crack the secret of the first normalization and I can't grasp it.